# Filtar object angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tengo :

```
var members = [
        { username: 'SheoNarayan', address: 'Hyderabad', pin : '500049' },
        { username: 'Munna', address: 'Bokaro', pin: '8256598' },
        { username: 'Jay', address: 'Aurangabad', pin: '824101' },
        { username: 'Sreeni', address: 'New York', pin: 'BY-524' }
];
```

y en mi html:

```
Jay : {{members | filter: { username: 'Jay'} }}  => esto me muestra { username: 'Jay', address: 'Aurangabad', pin: '824101' }
```

Pero yo quiero solo mostrar el pin de Jay y no quiero hacer un `ng-repeat` recorriendo todos para hacer un `ng-if`, ¿hay alguna forma de que me de lo que quiero directamente?

Comment: Si el arreglo no es dinámico ni pretendes ingresar más objetos en este, simplemente deberías acceder al index del objeto, en este caso sería `{{members[2].username}} : {{members[2].pin}}`; de lo contrario, la respuesta del colega `Hictus` sería una excelente opción.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconozco si se puede acceder directamente una propiedad del objeto de la manera que buscas, pero se me ocurre lo siguiente.

```
<li ng-repeat="member in members | filter: { username: 'Jay'}">
 <p>{{member.username}}:{{member.pin}}</p>
</li>
```

O si te ves muy motivado te haces tu propio filtro:

```
app.filter('nameFilter', function() {
    return function(elements,name) {
        for(elem in elements){
          if(elements[elem].username==name){
            return elements[elem].pin
          }
        }

        return name;
    };
});

Jay : {{members | nameFilter : 'Jay'}}
```

Aqui el [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HnGF5eOaiFxG7dsmT6XY)

Comment: Si te sirvió, no dudes en marcarla como aceptada ;)

Comment: es una solución lo malo es que tengo que recorrer los members y si tuviera muchos no se lo que podria tardar

Comment: La solución de @Findelias podría ser una buena alternativa, aunque de una manera u otra, los métodos de dicha librería, también recorrerán el array reduciendo el rendimiento en caso de ser un array muy muy grande.

Comment: si no hay un modo mas directo pues nada a usar el filtro, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Mi recomendación para estas cosas es la librería *Lodash*.

> [Aquí tienes su pagina oficial](https://lodash.com/)

Para estas cosas por ejemplo tiene el método find, del que puedes ver su documentación [aquí](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find)

En código tu problema se solventaría:

**JS**

```
var members = [
        { username: 'SheoNarayan', address: 'Hyderabad', pin : '500049' },
        { username: 'Munna', address: 'Bokaro', pin: '8256598' },
        { username: 'Jay', address: 'Aurangabad', pin: '824101' },
        { username: 'Sreeni', address: 'New York', pin: 'BY-524' }
];

var userJay = _.find(memebers, ['username', 'Jay']);
```

**HTML**

```
Jay : {{ userJay.pin }}
```

Comment: Ni idea de esta maravillosa librería, gracias por el aporte!